# mysql combine two select queries

Tags: php, mysql

I know this can be confusing, but please bear with me on this one.

I have two SELECT queries with a minor difference which returns pretty much the same result set.

```
SELECT products_id,options_values_id
    FROM products_attributes pa
    LEFT JOIN products_options po ON ( pa.options_id = po.products_options_id )
    WHERE products_id ='574' and pa.options_id!=6
    and pa.options_id!=3
    AND products_options_type = 6
    GROUP BY products_id,options_values_id
    ORDER BY products_id,products_options_sort_order,options_id
```

The second query varies at `products_options_type`

```
SELECT products_id,options_values_id
    FROM products_attributes pa
    LEFT JOIN products_options po ON ( pa.options_id = po.products_options_id )
    WHERE products_id ='574' and pa.options_id!=6
    and pa.options_id!=3
    AND products_options_type = 2
    GROUP BY products_id,options_values_id
    ORDER BY products_id,products_options_sort_order,options_id
```

And the results returned by them are

```
574|193
574|204
```

AND

```
574|25
574|3
```

I want the output as

```
574|193|25
574|204|3
```

What I tried is:

```
SELECT pa.products_id,pa.options_values_id,ord.options_values_id
        FROM products_attributes pa
        LEFT JOIN products_options po ON ( pa.options_id = po.products_options_id )


        LEFT JOIN(SELECT products_id,options_values_id
        FROM products_attributes pa
        LEFT JOIN products_options po ON ( pa.options_id = po.products_options_id )
        WHERE products_id ='574' and pa.options_id!=6
        and pa.options_id!=3
        AND products_options_type = 2
        GROUP BY products_id,options_values_id
        ORDER BY products_id,products_options_sort_order,options_id)ord ON pa.products_id=ord.products_id


        WHERE paproducts_id ='574' and pa.options_id!=6
        and pa.options_id!=3
        AND products_options_type = 2
        GROUP BY pa.products_id,pa.options_values_id
        ORDER BY pa.products_id,products_options_sort_order,options_id
```

However this returns

```
574|193|25
574|204|25
```

I am not too good with joins, so any idea if and how this can be done?

Comment: Why should your database engine know that 193 and 25 belong together as do 204 and 3? I could not know it, seeing your code.

Comment: Actually there isn't much logic in there, but I am working on a existing system, and I need a shortcut for this part( just don't ask why I need to cheat my way here).

Comment: My point is not that you don't have a reason why you need your data this way. Just that there is no way the enginge is able to sort the data without knowing how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT a.products_id,a.options_values_id, b.options_values_id
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rw', products_id, options_values_id
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, products_attributes pa
LEFT JOIN products_options po ON ( pa.options_id = po.products_options_id )
WHERE products_id ='574' and pa.options_id!=6
and pa.options_id!=3
AND products_options_type = 6
GROUP BY products_id,options_values_id
ORDER BY products_id,products_options_sort_order,options_id) a,
(SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rw', products_id,options_values_id
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, products_attributes pa
LEFT JOIN products_options po ON ( pa.options_id = po.products_options_id )
WHERE products_id ='574' and pa.options_id!=6
and pa.options_id!=3
AND products_options_type = 2
GROUP BY products_id,options_values_id
ORDER BY products_id,products_options_sort_order,options_id) b
WHERE a.products_id=b.products_id and a.rw=b.rw;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query, here i took join on `product_options` twice, 1 for `po.products_options_type = 6` and 2nd for `po1.products_options_type = 2`

```
SELECT pa.products_id,po.options_values_id,po1.options_values_id
FROM products_attributes pa
LEFT JOIN products_options po ON ( pa.options_id = po.products_options_id and po.products_options_type = 6)
LEFT JOIN products_options po1 ON ( pa.options_id = po1.products_options_id and po.products_options_type = 2)
WHERE pa.products_id ='574' and pa.options_id!=6
and pa.options_id!=3
GROUP BY products_id,po1.options_values_id,po1.options_values_id
ORDER BY products_id,products_options_sort_order,options_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

```
select v1,v2,v3, v4 from (SELECT products_id v1,options_values_id v2
    FROM products_attributes pa
    LEFT JOIN products_options po ON ( pa.options_id = po.products_options_id )
    WHERE products_id ='574' and pa.options_id!=6
    and pa.options_id!=3
    AND products_options_type = 6
    GROUP BY products_id,options_values_id
    ORDER BY products_id,products_options_sort_order,options_id) t1,    
(SELECT products_id v3,options_values_i v4
    FROM products_attributes pa
    LEFT JOIN products_options po ON ( pa.options_id = po.products_options_id )
    WHERE products_id ='574' and pa.options_id!=6
    and pa.options_id!=3
    AND products_options_type = 2
    GROUP BY products_id,options_values_id
    ORDER BY products_id,products_options_sort_order,options_id) t2
where t1.products_id=t2.products_id
```

You can sort it easily.